# Can two people simultaneously invent exactly same thing in a very specialized domain?

Tags: fallacies

There are two people. Let's call those people as A and B.  Person "A" has calm personality and Person "B" has aggressive personality. B has aggressive personality because the B person lives in a culture where they values seriousness and directness.

Both A and B works in a popular industry. Let's call this industry as Y. Within the Y Industry, there are very narrow specialized domains.

Recently, the Person A find himself that the Person B invented exactly same thing with same attributes.

Person A find it's very hard to believe it happened and simultaneously Person B find it's very hard to believe that there is other person who invented exactly same thing.

Person A have a conversion with Person B and ask him how he got the idea. Person B described  he was inspired by several things. Those several things are independently validated by Person A. Person A concluded that it's possible for Person B to have the same idea by having a deep observation to those several things mentioned by Person B.

However, Person A is still in denial, because Person B is less experienced than him and Person A believes that it's quite hard for anyone with lower experience to come up with the thing Person A invented.

Person A haven't told anyone about the invention and he found about Person B invented the same thing thru advertisements.

Person A suspects IP thief here. Person A believes either his suppliers or his vendors are compromised.  Person A however lack a direct proof that such a thief ever occurred.

Person A aware that great minds think alike; however, the person A find it's hard for someone with aggressive or child-alike behavior to become intellectual enough to invent the same thing he invented.

Comment: if your 5th paragraph actually happened, then why not? did it?

Comment: most things are pretty trivial, and I've written lots of weird things with "copyleft" on them. the question is so vacuous and obviously answered, that it seems you have an agenda to disown and insult person A. I've not heard of any IP court cases, and frankly they sound like "money"

Comment: I'm the Person A here. Person B aim to sell the product very expensively than I could ever imagined. You know based on what I found, I can't neither distrust or trust 5th paragraph.

Comment: I was seeing his posts on social media and they don't look intellectual enough to me. Very aggressive hence I strongly consider IP thief here, but I'm more interested finding the source of thief than suing him on Court.

Comment: In one of post, he publicly attacked me and called me "low brain, chicken brain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as posed in the title:

The invention of the thermal inkjet principle (a highly specialized domain!) was done almost simultaneously by scientists at Canon and Hewlett-Packard in the early 1980s- so yes, it is not impossible for this to occur.

I cannot address any of the other questions in the body of your posting here.

Comment: Which other questions? Can you be specific? I might be able to elaborate them further.

Comment: @jeffbRTC, at HP and Canon, neither side displayed the attributes you assign to persons A and B. This means my personal experience furnishes me with nothing to reason with on the topic of your A and B, their motives, purposes, personalities, etc. -NN